# Can I add external testers to test flight for testing the binary that has been rejected by app store review?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, testflight

I am new to ios and I submitted my first app to app store for review.

It got rejected as it was too simple for approval to the app store. However that was the requirement of the app and I am in touch with the review commitee to reconsider.

Till such time, I need to give a demo to my customer for the same through test flight.

Can I add an external tester for the same version build of the app that was rejected by the store?

Please guide me.

Thanks,

Regards,
khm

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can definitely add share build to your customer by adding in External Tester and invite for same build.